# I want to change the color of my data points in my plot for some variables

Tags: python, plot, colors

I have 2 lists contain some data. I plot as X vs Y. However, I want to group them by changing the color of the data points, depending on the values of x and y. For instance, if x>10 and y<20 data points will be red. Here is the plot part of my code:

```
fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=300)

ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
   
ax.errorbar(X, R, xerr=Xe/5, yerr=Re,fmt='o',marker='.',linestyle='None', markeredgecolor='blue', markerfacecolor='blue',markersize= 2, elinewidth=.5,
             ecolor='black', capsize=1, capthick=.5)
```